# Oracle Apex - 18.2 - Interactive Grid POPUP LOV issues

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid where on click of a button , I insert rows into the table of the interactive grid.
Now when I edit for few columns of the grid - (These columns are of type Popup LOV), the values get inserted into other columns as well.

For eg : If the table has columns Qty, Item, name1 , name2 and there are 2 rows in the table where only qty and item are filled and name1 and name 2 are null.

If I edit name1 which is a Popup LOV, the same value is displayed into name2.

Please help!

Comment: Did you review NAME2 properties? Is there anything that looks suspicious?

Comment: @Littlefoot The only thing that looks suspicious is this setting. Setting : Input Field -Not Enterable,Show display value and Store Return Value . Fetch - Fetch First Rowset

Comment: I've just logged in and saw that you fixed it; primary key, eh? I'm glad you found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! I didn't set the primary key of the IG to be a unique key,hence the occurrence of the above mentioned issues.